# inject a bar chart into a webpage via content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chart.js

I am going to inject a bar chart into a webpage according to the data presented on the page.

I created a Chrome extension for this purpose, which used [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/) to draw the bar chart, but didn't work. The following is a sample, so how to fix ?

One can download my extension [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w0y29kI5zSG6eDxzZZt4gUR_WYubnDsF/view?usp=sharing).

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "JsonAnalysis2",
  "description": "Json Analysis",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "nativeMessaging",
     "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["chart.js","contentScript.js"]

    }
  ],
  "page_action": {
      "default_title": "",
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

contentScript.js

```
// var jq = document.createElement('script');
// jq.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0";
// document.querySelector('head').appendChild(jq);

analysisResult=`

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '购买记录',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
             // backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            borderColor:'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>


`


document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin',analysisResult)
```

Comment: Scripts in innerHTML or insertAdjacentHTML are not executed so this won't work.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried with `document.querySelector('body').appendChild(script);` didn't work either

Comment: Yes, it won't work either because content scripts run in their own context ("isolated world"). I don't understand why you're creating a separate script.

Comment: So what should I do ?

Comment: Simply use the code as is, I guess? Without creating the extra script elements.

Answer (score 0):

After changed `manifest.json` to the following , it worked ! One could download the working sample [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K3SPcW4shaGuIx14TsvePgc6Lt5NO687/view?usp=sharing).

```
analysisResult=`
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
`

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin',analysisResult)


var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '购买记录',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
             // backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            borderColor:'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```